# Expected Primary expression in header and cpp

Tags: c++

SO I have to two files a header named "colors.h" and a source file called "colors.cpp". In the header file inside of the namespace clr I am trying to prototype 3 functions and then I want to define them in the cpp file. For some reason the compiler wont let me prototype or define the function instead I get expected primary expression. I know what this essentially means but in the context I'm lost as to why it would happen.

```
#include "colors.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace clr{

    void set(color c){
        std::cout << c;
    }
    void print(color  c,std::string  s){
    }
    void frame(useconds_t usec){
    }
};
```

header

```
#ifndef COLOR_H
#define COLOR_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

namespace color {

    string black = "\033[0;30m";
    string red  = "\033[0;31m";
    string green  = "\033[0;32m";
    string yellow  = "\033[0;33m";
    string blue  = "\033[0;34m";
    string magenta  = "\033[0;35m";
    string cyan  = "\033[0;36m";
    string white  = "\033[0;37m";
    string reset = "\033[0;39m";

};

namespace clr{

    void clr:: set(color c);

    void print(color c, std::string s);

    void frame(useconds_t usec);
};

#endif
```

Comment: On what line is this error? Also color is a namespace, not a type so it can't be used as such.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The errors are on the lines within the clr namespace with all three functions in both files. And ah ok well I was suppose to use an enum datatype to define the colors and I assumed that meant to make a namespace. I'm guessing I should actually use the enum method?

Comment: ` #ifndef COLOR_H
#define COLOR_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

enum color {

COLOR_BLACK,
COLOR_RED,
COLOR_GREEN,
COLOR_YELLOW,
COLOR_BLUE,
COLOR_MAGENTA,
COLOR_CYAN,
COLOR_WHITE,
COLOR_RESET,

};

namespace clr{

void set(color c);

void print(color c, std::string s);

void frame(useconds_t usec);
};

#endif`,
after changing it to enum I think I fixed the issue but I am getting an undefined reference to main and I'm assuming that's just because colors.cpp does not have a main function.

Answer (score 0):

You're being a little inconsistent with the use of your namespaces and variable definitions.  Try the following:

the header:

```
#ifndef COLOR_H
#define COLOR_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

namespace color {
    typedef const std::string colour;

    colour black = "\033[0;30m";
    colour red  = "\033[0;31m";
    colour green  = "\033[0;32m";
    colour yellow  = "\033[0;33m";
    colour blue  = "\033[0;34m";
    colour magenta  = "\033[0;35m";
    colour cyan  = "\033[0;36m";
    colour white  = "\033[0;37m";
    colour reset = "\033[0;39m";
};

namespace clr{
    void set(color::colour c);
    void print(color::colour c, std::string s);    
    void frame(useconds_t usec);
};
```

And for the .cpp file:

```
namespace clr{
    void set(color::colour c){  std::cout << c; }
    void print(color::colour c,std::string  s){ /*do something*/;  }
    void frame(useconds_t usec){ /* do something*/; }
};
```

There are more elegant ways of writing this, though I tried to make as few of changes to your code as possible (for example, in production code, I would never use both color and colour - too confusing for my feeble mind).  However this seems to work on my system (compile and run).